# Zero Energy Wavefunctions in 1D P-Wave Kitaev Model

Tags: condensed-matter, wavefunction, superconductivity, hamiltonian, majorana-fermions

$\bf{Setup}$

Hi! I am trying to derive the wavefunctions of the zero energy solutions of the Schrodinger equation in a 1D p-wave superconductor (Kitaev model). I am starting with the Hamiltonian

$
\begin{equation}
H = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\epsilon_k & \Delta^{\ast}_k\\
\Delta_k & -\epsilon_k
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
$

where $\epsilon_k = -\mu - t\cos{k}$ ($\mu$ is the chemical potential, $t$ the hopping parameter, and $k$ the crystal momentum) and $\Delta = -i\Delta\sin{k}$ ($\Delta$ is a pairing parameter from the superconductivity). Zero energy modes are thought to exist near the gap closing at the Fermi energy.

$\bf{Solution\quad Attempt}$

We can define

$$
\begin{equation}
H\Psi = 0
\end{equation}
$$

It was suggested that I assume $\epsilon_k$ is linear and approximate it in terms of Fermi velocity, $v_F$. I had some difficulty determining how to define the Fermi velocity without taking the partial derivative of the full dispersion relation, $E(k) = \sqrt{\epsilon_k^2 + \Delta_k^2}$. So I decided to Taylor expand around the Fermi momentum (the zero modes are thought to occur near this point)

$$
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_k = -\mu - t\cos{k} \rightarrow \mu - t\cos{k_F} + t\sin{k_F}(k-k_F)
\\ \Delta = -i\Delta\sin{k} \rightarrow -i\Delta\sin{k_F} -i\Delta\cos{k_F}(k-k_F)
\end{equation}
$$

If I define Fermi velocity as $\frac{\partial\epsilon_k}{\partial k}$ then $v_F = t\sin{k_F}$, and also that $\frac{dv_F}{dk} = 0$ (my justification being that the "acceleration" at the Fermi level would be 0 since it is the maximum momentum value), these become

$$
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_k = -\mu - t\sin{k_F}(k-k_F)
\\ \Delta = -i\Delta\sin{k_F}
\end{equation}
$$

I assume $\mu$ is $0$ because we are looking at the Fermi level. So

$$
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_k = t\sin{k_F}(k-k_F) \rightarrow v_Fp\\
\Delta = -i\Delta_{k_F}
\end{equation}
$$

where $p=(k-k_F)$ is the momentum with respect to the Fermi level, which I replace by $p \rightarrow -i\partial_x$ (justification that the momentum near the Fermi level follows the same form everywhere) and $\Delta_{k_F} = \frac{v_F\Delta}{t}$. So my simplified Hamiltonian becomes

$$
\begin{equation}
H = 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
v_Fp & i\Delta_{k_F}\\
-i\Delta_{k_F} & -v_Fp
\end{array}
\right] = v_Fp\sigma_z - \Delta_{k_F}\sigma_y
\end{equation}
$$

($\sigma$'s are the Pauli Matrices) I then multiply from the left by $\sigma_z$, assume a wavefunction form of $\Psi = \chi_{\nu}\phi$, with $\chi_{\nu}$ an eigenvector of $\sigma_x$ (the first term in the simplified Hamiltonian is the identity matrix after multiplying by $\sigma_z$) and $\phi \propto e^{\lambda x}$.

$\bf{Question}$

Are my assumptions for the simplifications of the Hamiltonian matrix elements correct? Is my understanding of Fermi velocity and its derivative okay?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Self-promotion: we obtained the wave-functions in the Andreev approximation for the 1D p-wave superconductor of finite length in http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2519, see appendix.

Comment: What do you use as your definition of Fermi velocity in equation A2?

Comment: I do not understand, the Fermi velocity is the p-derivative of the band structure. Is that what you want to know ?